# ARMv4, ARMv5E, ARMv6 assembly usage on iOS devices with ARMv7 and ARMv8-A (arm64) instructions sets

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

There is a plenty of libraries written in C with assembly (for ARMv7) optimized versions of some functions which boost performance significantly (some of them making use of NEON). In this case I know that I should better use optimized versions of them.

Now I have a library written in C which has some functions written both in C and ARMv4, ARMv5E assembly. With default compile configuration it doesn't try to use this assembly code on iOS devices. I wonder if I should bother trying to enable it.

Is it possible to use assembly source code for ARMv4, ARMv5E, ARMv6 instructions sets on iOS devices with ARMv7 and ARMv8-A (arm64) instructions sets?

If yes, does it give performance boost comparing to the similar code written in C and compiled for ARMv7 and ARMv8-A (arm64)?

And another question: does one need ARMv8-A (arm64) optimized NEON assembly code? How does this compatibility work in general? Here I mean only AArch64 and not AArch32. For this question lets pretend that I have to build binary for AArch64 only which should be truly 64 bit and doesn't contain any 32 bit code.

I would appreciate if someone could answer with a compatibility table or a link to one.

EDIT: I have slightly edited my question as suggested by  **Notlikethat**.

EDIT2: I wanted to give some details after **Notlikethat** answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone who reads this question.

1. *Now I have a library written in C which has some functions written both in C and ARMv4, ARMv5E assembly. [...] I wonder if I should bother trying to enable it.* - The functions written in assembly are purely for performance and don't do anything that can't be done in C.
2. *Does one need ARMv8-A (arm64) optimized NEON assembly code?* - If one has NEON optimized code for ARMv7 does he/she need to adopt/change it for ARMv8-A?

Comment: My answer would be roughly "it depends; it depends; in what sense?" which suggests the question needs to be rather more specific. When you say "ARMv8-A (arm64)" are you only considering the AArch64 state (which is an entirely new architecture), or AArch32 state as well (which is _almost_ fully backwards-compatible with v7)?

Comment: @Notlikethat - Could you please describe in separate answer "it depends; it depends; in what sense?". I would really appreciate that much detailed answer and I think not only me.

Comment: @dwelch - I have tried to search for compatibility table at infocenter.arm.com but couldn't find any. Could you please give direct link or tell where should I look?

Comment: get the documentation for each processor and compare them side by side.  Gotta do some of the work yourself, cant expect it to be handed to you.  If you are already knowledgeable about the pre armv8 architectures then all you have to do is look at the armv8 documentation to see what changed.  Or at least compare the asm code you have to the architecture you want to run it on, or even simpler just try to assemble it and let the tools tell you what is wrong.  You could have done this several times over by now, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok, I was expecting from someone who has experience in the field either a quick small answer or a detailed answer (which would be very useful for anyone reading this question) or no answer at all (if you don't know or don't want to share). Answers like "Do it by yourself" help little. If I had expertise to do it by myself at the moment(for reasonable time) I wouldn't post this question.

Comment: Hand-optimized code targeting armv4 or armv5 is going to be quite sub-optimal on "big core" armv7 or armv8 processors (and won't run on AArch64 at all) -- they are radically different architecturally.  Better to use C code or to find library implementations that target the processors of interest.  What operations do you actually need?

Comment: @StephenCanon this is rather general question about armv4 armv5 assembly usage on newer architectures. I understand that performance depends on some particular implementations and needs. Thanks for one more confirmation that I better use C or find implementations that target armv7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll bite. This isn't an answer so much as a random selection of details and opinions to illustrate why the question is still fundamentally unanswerable, but which may tangentially contain some useful information around the subject. And entertainingly excessive use of emphasis.

> Now I have a library written in C which has some functions written both in C and ARMv4, ARMv5E assembly. [...] I wonder if I should bother trying to enable it.

"I have a plant here, I wonder if I should bother trying to eat it." *Rather depends on whether it's a lettuce or a holly bush, doesn't it?* I'm **guessing** the assembly was there as a pure performance thing, rather than to implement something that simply can't be expressed in a higher-level language. Whatever it does, *does it make your program measurably faster/better if you **do** enable it?* Hand-tuned assembly for a v4-era core isn't likely to be particularly optimal for a modern 15+ stage superscalar out-of-order pipeline anyway, so it's not unreasonable that the compiler might do a better job with access to newer instructions and suitable optimisation settings - It knows more about instruction scheduling and cycle timings than you or I do. On the other hand, maybe it *is* something awkward that the optimiser can't catch, but can be done efficiently with a handful of the more esoteric instructions. The only real way to make a judgement like that is to *try it and see*.

> Is it possible to use assembly source code for ARMv4, ARMv5E, ARMv6 instructions sets on iOS devices with ARMv7 [...] instructions sets?

*In most cases*. Except if you use deprecated instructions like `SWP`, which may or may not fault depending on how the device is set up. Or depend on the pre-v6 unaligned access behaviour. Or any implementation-defined features that just happened to be consistent across previous devices. Or any of the other features of the architecture which have subtly changed over the years. The v6 architecture was the most significant shift, but helpfully, Appendices L and O of [the v7 ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) consist of 102 pages detailing the changes all the way back to v4. *Without knowing your code in detail*, how can **we** say what, if any, of that is relevant?

> Is it possible to use assembly source code for ARMv4, ARMv5E, ARMv6 instructions sets on iOS devices with [...] ARMv8-A (arm64) instructions sets?

No. AArch64 is a completely new architecture, new instruction set, new assembly language. Many concepts, mnemonics and the general *feel* of the syntax are familiar from what is now AArch32, but the instruction set is a fundamentally different design. For starters the register names are different - the sort of thing that reading [any kind of manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801a/BABJFBJG.html) would have told you straight away.

> If yes, does it give performance boost comparing to the similar code written in C and compiled for ARMv7 and ARMv8-A (arm64)?

Are we talking the careful selection of the algorithm that best suits the architecture, tuned for a particular microarchitecture implementation by an expert with detailed knowledge of the pipeline model, cycle timings, etc., or the kind of naïve "assembly is faster, innit?" code which ends up being 4 times slower than what the compiler spits out on `-O1`? (Nothing ARM-specific about this one, either) In any case, *see question 1*.

> does one need ARMv8-A (arm64) optimized NEON assembly code?

You don't *need* it, you could always just have slow code. Of course, if you're doing SIMD-type operations it'd be a bit silly not to use NEON but you don't necessarily need to go straight to assembly - if you're doing straightforward loop-based stuff an auto-vectorising compiler may take care of it. For more complex things, the figures I've seen (from someone who definitely knows what they're doing) suggest intrinsics can get you about 70-95% of the speed of hand-tuned assembly, for a lot less effort. For absolute maximum performance then yeah, fire up the assembler and spend weeks microbenchmarking your cache misses and register stalls as you tweak it to perfection.

> How does this compatibility work in general?

*What compatibility*? The one that doesn't exist on account of it being a different instruction set?

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer. Basically it covers around 95% of that I wanted to know. I see now that you had to guess in some places what I really wanted to ask but fortunately for me you have guessed correctly :).